# Get UserId by passing email ID in the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api, users

The Stack Exchange API is mostly based on 'ids'. IE

```
/2.2/users/{ids}/top-tags?site=stackoverflow
```

How can we get {ids} for a particular user using his email id or name? Is there any method available to get details about a particular user in stack exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot search for a user by email address.  Email accounts are sensitive private information and not disclosed by Stack Exchange.

You can search for users by display-name though. See [the documentation for `/users`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).  You can use the `inname` parameter.

For example:
[/2.2/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=Stack&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=Stack&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Returns all the users on Stack Overflow that have `stack` (case insensitive) in their display name.